# Accessing method from objects in a dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x

is it possible to access to an external class method from a loop into a dictionary? 
Here 2 examples, one access by a loop into a list and the other one by a dictionary. The first one does the job I'd like to reach with the dictionary (the second one):

```
ins.py

class Ins:
    def __init__(self, cognome, nome, indirizzo, entrate, spese):
        self.__cognome = cognome
        self.__nome = nome
        self.__indirizzo = indirizzo
        self.__entrate = entrate
        self.__spese = spese

    def get_cognome(self):
        return self.__cognome

    def get_nome(self):
        return self.__nome

    def get_indirizzo(self):
        return self.__indirizzo

    def get_totale(self):
        return str(float(self.__entrate) - float(self.__spese))

    def __str__(self):
        return "Cognome: " + self.__cognome + "\nNome: " + self.__nome + \
                 "\nIndirizzo: " + self.__indirizzo +\
                 "\nEntrate: " + self.__entrate + "\nSpese: " + self.__spese
ins_main_list.py   

import ins
dict = []

def main():
    again = 'y'
    while again.lower() == 'y':
        cognome = input('Inserire Cognome: ')
        nome = input('Inserire Nome: ')
        indirizzo = input('Inserire Indirizzo: ')
        entrate = input('Inserire Entrate: ')
        spese = input('Inserire Spese: ')
        again = input("Continuare con l'inserimento? (Y/N) ")
        print()
        entry = ins.Ins(cognome, nome, indirizzo, entrate, spese)
        dict.append(entry)
    for item in dict:
        print(item)
        print(item.get_totale())
        print()

 main()

ins_main_dict.py

import ins
dict = {}

def main():
    again = 'y'
    while again.lower() == 'y':
        cognome = input('Inserire Cognome: ')
        nome = input('Inserire Nome: ')
        indirizzo = input('Inserire Indirizzo: ')
        entrate = input('Inserire Entrate: ')
        spese = input('Inserire Spese: ')
        again = input("Continuare con l'inserimento? (Y/N) ")
        print()
        entry = ins.Ins(cognome, nome, indirizzo, entrate, spese)
        dict[cognome] = entry
    for item in dict:
        print(dict[item])
        print(item.get_totale())
        print()

main()
```

As you can see in the last example item.get_totale() give me an attribute error. How is possible to access into it?

Comment: Where is your error coming from? Post the full error message including the stack trace

Comment: As an aside, you probably shouldn't be using double-underscore name-mangling, and for that matter, writing a bunch of getter methods...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you should be doing `dict[item].get_totale()`, not `item.get_totale()`. `item` is iterating over the keys of `dict` (which are strings), not your custom class

Comment: Yes. You just loop over the keys with: for item in dict: Another possibility would be: for item in dict.values()